# how to change Jquery datepicker date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i am need to do is to display data format

> dd-mm-yy

but when it submitting format should

> be mm-dd-yy

so any possible way to do this?

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: you may have to maintain a hidden input field for submit purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)** option:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

For more:

- [option-dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)
- [utility-formatDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)